# REGEXP_SUBSTR : extracting portion of string between [ ] including []

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am on Oracle 11gR2.

I am trying to extract the text between '[' and ']' including [].

ex:

```
    select regexp_substr('select userid,username from tablename where user_id=[REQ.UID] and username=[REQD.VP.UNAME]','\[(.*)\]') from dual
```

Output:

```
    [REQ.UID] and username=[REQD.VP.UNAME]
```

Output needed:

```
    [REQ.UID][REQD.VP.UNAME]
```

Please let me know how to get the needed output.

Thanks & Regards,
Bishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are just going to have two occurrences of [] then the following should suffice. The ? in the .*? means that it is non-greedy so that it doesn't gobble up the last ].

```
select
 regexp_replace('select userid,username from tablename where user_id=[REQ.UID] and username=[REQD.VP.UNAME]'
,'.*(\[.*?\]).*(\[.*?\]).*','\1\2')
from dual
;
```

Comment: Another small doubt: How do I handle Multiline in the same example?

Comment: For multiline you need to use the `match_parameter` of `regexp_replace` to accept newlines as any characters. So, `regexp_replace('select userid,username from tablename where user_id=[REQ.UID] and username=[REQD.VP.UNAME]','.*(\[.*?\]).*(\[.*?\]).*','\1\2',1,0,'n')` - see [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Oracle user, but from quick perusal of the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm), I think this should be close:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('select userid,username from tablename where user_id=[REQ.UID] and username=[REQD.VP.UNAME]',
               '^[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*\])[^\[]*(\[[^\]]*\])$', '\1 \2')
```

Which looks much nastier than it is.

Pattern is:

- `^[^\[]*`   Capture all characters up to (but not including) the first `[`
- `(\[[^\]]*\])`  Capture into group 1 anything like `[<not "]">]`
- `[^\[]*` Capture everything up to (nut not including) the next `[`
- `(\[[^\]]*\])`  Capture into group 2 anything like `[<not "]">]`, at the end of the string

Then the replacement is simple, just `<grp 1> <grp 2>`